# Solutions to $f(x^2) = 2f(x)^2-1$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, functional-equations

I'm looking for solutions over $\mathbb{R}$ to the functional equation:

$$f(x^2) = 2f(x)^2 -1$$

The left hand side is very similar to the expansion for $\cos(2\theta)$. But the right hand side involves a power of $2$, not a multiple of $2$. Wondering if anyone can classify the set of solutions.

Comment: $f(x)=cos(k.log(x))$ satisfies the equation

Comment: Why not answer the question?

Comment: @Mehdi your solution is for $x>0$, right?

Comment: @GEdgar You are right. To cover negative numbers, we can use absolute function as $f(x) = cos(k.log|x|),~x\ne0$ and since there is no  condition for continuity.  $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. Edited

Comment: I think you could even replace $k$ with any function in $\log x$ with period $\log 2$.

Comment: What types of functions are you looking for? Continuous? Differentiable? Smooth?